# Gaming compatibility?

Tags: 15.10, games, compatibility

My Dell Inspiron notebook 3542 has a i3 quad-core processor and Intel HD Graphics.
But, is Ubuntu gaming compatible? Or I need to install Windows?
I am talking about games like Counter Strike, NFS Most Wanted, Dota, etc.

Comment: Many games have been ported to Ubuntu. See [Steam's list of Linux games](http://store.steampowered.com/search/?os=linux). However, some games may need Windows - though you can run them through the Windows emulator Wine or a virtual Windows install on VirtualBox.

Comment: To your edit: [Dota 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/570/) is on Linux, [CounterStrike](http://store.steampowered.com/app/730/) is on Linux - but no NFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaming in Linux is still behind, but so much better than a couple years ago (don't get me started on 15 years ago).

The drivers for Intel based cards are quite good on Linux, even though the card probably won't allow you gaming new games on high quality settings.

The best sources for commercial Linux games are in order of my personal preference:

- Steam (http://store.steampowered.com/search/?os=linux)
- Humble bundle (store and bundles, some items are even drm free) (https://www.humblebundle.com/)
- GOG.com (completely drm free) (https://www.gog.com/games?system=lin_mint,lin_ubuntu&sort=bestselling&page=1)

If you are interested in running Linux as a gamer, now is a great time to do it. But if all you want is gaming and you don't mind Windows 10 (not UI wise, but the privacy and store developments), you might be better off there.

If you own those games in Steam on Windows, just give Linux a try, all the games you currently own that are available in Linux (Dota 2 and csgo are among them), you can already play without buying them again.

On a personal note, I've been dual booting for over 15 years now, always keeping a Windows partition for gaming. Since the release of Windows 10 and the advancements of Steam I finally use Linux as my primary gaming system as well.